# Unity how to keep player travelling randomly on path

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to recreate the game in the below link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88kMVPzybSw

So far I have been successful in generating a random path with no jumps yet (putting jumps is not a problem). I am not storing the information for this randomness so how can I make my player follow the path?

EDIT: This is my tilemanager class. using this Im generating a random path. My question is how can i force my player to move along this path by itself as in the above game?

```
public class TileManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] tilePrefabs;
    public GameObject currentTile;

    private Stack<GameObject> leftTiles = new Stack<GameObject>();
    private Stack<GameObject> topTiles = new Stack<GameObject>();


    private static TileManager instance;

    public static TileManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<TileManager>();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public Stack<GameObject> LeftTiles
    {
        get {   return leftTiles; }
        set {   leftTiles = value; }
    }

    public Stack<GameObject> TopTiles
    {
        get{    return topTiles; }
        set{    topTiles = value; }
    }



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {

        CreateTiles(50);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            SpawnTile();
        }


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

    }

    public void CreateTiles(int amount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            LeftTiles.Push(Instantiate(tilePrefabs[0]));
            TopTiles.Push(Instantiate(tilePrefabs[1]));
            LeftTiles.Peek().name = "LeftTile";
            LeftTiles.Peek().SetActive(false);
            TopTiles.Peek().name = "TopTile";
            TopTiles.Peek().SetActive(false);
        }

    }

    public void SpawnTile() {

        //before we spawn we need to check if theres enough tiles, if not create more.
        if (LeftTiles.Count == 0 || TopTiles.Count == 0) {
            CreateTiles(10);
        }

        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0,2);

        if (randomIndex == 0) {
            GameObject temp = LeftTiles.Pop();
            temp.SetActive(true);
            temp.transform.position = currentTile.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(randomIndex).position;
            currentTile = temp;
        }
        else if(randomIndex == 1)
        {
            GameObject temp = TopTiles.Pop();
            temp.SetActive(true);
            temp.transform.position = currentTile.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(randomIndex).position;
            currentTile = temp;
        }

        int spawnPickUp = Random.Range(0 , 10);
        if (spawnPickUp == 0) {
            currentTile.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        //currentTile = (GameObject) Instantiate(tilePrefabs[randomIndex], currentTile.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(randomIndex).position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    public void ResetGame() {
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }
}
```

[image: this is a snap shot of my scene view]

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far. Thanks!

Comment: This question is very vague and not specific in any way

Comment: It depends on how you create your path.

Comment: you guys are right, I have updated the question with more information hope this helps

Comment: Use a path-finding algorithm e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: I thought about that but is that really necessary? Isnt there any quick fix method that might be better? For example, to check if I fall off I use a ray cast. is there any way of knowing not the game object im on but the very next one in front?

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of your path like you would a linked list, with references from one tile to the next.

Each individual tile is already a prefab, so add a simple MonoBehavior script to that prefab:

```
public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Tile NextTile;
}
```

Then your spawn function could be:

```
public void SpawnTile() 
{
    //Check if you need to create tile

    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0,2);

    if (randomIndex == 0) 
    {
        //Create the new tile and assign its position
        GameObject temp = LeftTiles.Pop();
        temp.SetActive(true);
        temp.transform.position = currentTile.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(randomIndex).position;

        //NEW: Assign the previous tile
        currentTile.GetComponent<Tile>().NextTile = temp;

        //Update current tile
        currentTile = temp;
    }
    else if(randomIndex == 1)
    {
       //Similar for top tiles
    }

    //Spawn Pickups
}
```

If you know what tile the player is currently on, you can always get the next tile in the path. Since tiles only reference the next tile, you can safely get rid of previous tiles without breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Queue. When creating a tile add it to Queue if you want player to move on path just give him full Queue object.

```
void MoveOnPath()
{
  Vector3 nextPos = Queue.Dequeue().position;
  And use transform or rigidbody to move player in right direction.
  if(playerpos==nextpos)
    MoveOnPath();
}
```